# Android: Bitmap memory out

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I knw this is one of the most discussed question but I couldn't figure out my way with the questions available here.

I'm decoding the bitmap as below

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sdCardPath);
```

While executing above line randomly system running out of memory. This is not happening always . For example if I try to decode same image 3 times, it might go out of memory 3rd time or even 4th time. This error observed randomly.

How to solve this issue??

Thanks for your time in advance

Comment: This is a pretty common issue. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue/823966#823966 for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It did help me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if this is a bitmap that you are referencing from your assets, I would recommend moving it to your `res/drawables` folder, and access it as a drawable. If this is not the case, you are making too many references to this image without, as @VargaPeter pointed out, garbage collecting. The best way to garbage collect when using multiple bitmaps is to call [recycle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29), however `System.gc()` is often used as well (though in practice, you should use `recycle()`. If you are still having problems, you must either (a) allocate more space using the Android NDK (discouraged), or (b) use a smaller bitmap image (recommended). I know for certain there are posts discussing option b in several places on this site, as I had this same problem once before.

Answer (score 1):

The Bitmap that you get back probably isn't garbage-collected because of a lingering reference.. Try to use the same reference if the app's design allows, or reusing a small number or references...

Comment: This is a very generic answer to any of the out of memory scenario. It doesn't help :( and I don't have much references as u suspect.